# VPS - Sending mails fails on ubuntu via postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, vps, hetzner

i have a VPS on Hetzner and struggling with sending mails. They says that block outgoing port 25, 465.

I have tried to change postfix configurations to change the port for smtp to 587 but still unable to send mails to others.

Anyone have any idea how i can run successfully a mail server?

Comment: The vast majority of mail servers require that your mail server adheres to the standard and delivers mail addressed for them over port 25, the standard SMTP port. Although you can configure your  mailserver to use a different port that won’t get your messages accepted by your intended recipients. - But are you sure that  hetzner blocks smtp ? Because my server experienced  no problem sending mail

Comment: @HBruijn I understand they have more of a "we reserve the right" firewalling policy to protect their hourly billed services, only made official a few years ago and not applied to already existing/vetted customers.